# How do you run from combat in Assassin's Creed II?

Tags: assassins-creed-2

I am trying to escape in Chapter 3, when you train with Mario. How do you do it on PC? I just don't get it.

Comment: Please only use the tag of the game you are actually having troubles with; adding additional tags only confuses the issue.

Answer (score 2):

To "escape", HOLD  <kbd>RMB</kbd> and <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, then at the same time, press a movement key.

Make sure you do this while locked onto a target